# Is there a method for using a nested class as a type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, class, types

I have a nested class that I'm trying to use as a type for a variable, but instead I'm getting the error `'A' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here`

```
class A {
    static B = class {

    }
    c: A.B;
}
```

How do I go about using a nested class as a type?

Comment: [sure you can](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#class-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Typescript does support [anonymous class expresions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#class-expressions), but you can't use them as a type (It is not possible to refer to the class instance type of a class expression outside the class expression).

You need to define the class outside the outer class (in your case class A) then use it to type your class A members.

```
class B {
   ....
}

class A {
    static b: B;
    c: B;
}
```

Comment: TypeScript does support [class expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#class-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

The value `A.B` is an (anonymous) class constructor.  There is no *type* named `B` or `A.B`, since named class instance types only get created upon class *statements*, and you have used a [class *expression*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#class-expressions).  Luckily, if you want the type of that constructor, you can get it as `typeof A.B`.  And if you want the type of an *instance* created by that constructor, you can use the [`InstanceType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypet) utlity type.

For example:

```
class A {
    static B = class {
        x = 1;
        y = ""
    }
    c: InstanceType<typeof A.B> = new A.B();
}
```

That should hopefully behave as you expect:

```
const a = new A();
a.c.x.toFixed();
a.c.y.toUpperCase();
```

To recap: in general if you have a class constructor value named `X` you should be able to get its instance type as `InstanceType<typeof X>` (give or take generics and other edge cases).  If `X` was declared as a class statement there's also a type named `X` corresponding to `InstanceType<typeof X>`.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7oQC5iwS2GgCFoBeaUSGZNDOgDzOgEYBuVOugTyYCJeOGAL6D0wAFzQAkgDtsYGcACmAFS4AHJQB4sGpQHsAZnAB0RAHxMZSgO6miACgCU7FCJSpg+uVmhgrtnDOrmAmwCb0Jlj6AGJ49EoAJsGooeFcUfoAquqaAE4AwpBKwUA)